# Installed OpenCV, but not recognized in code?

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv

I tried to install OpenCV using [this](https://youtu.be/pzuwrYgOnDQ) tutorial, but it keeps giving me an error with the code (pasted below). I spent a few hours trying to look up solutions for this problem, but I found nothing. I matched the tutorial almost the same as the person in the video except I wasn't abled to import the module of the entire OpenCV folder (I just imported the SDK), but I don't think that would cause such a huge issue. Any solution to this problem?

```
private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

static
{
    //OpenCVLoader symbol cannot be resolved.
    if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is Configured or Connected Successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not working or Loaded.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check again did you import `sdk\java` folder...? or just `sdk` because there is a difference between them.

Comment: I tried both of them. - I know its supposed to be sdk\java, but that didn't work. After a while I tried just sdk and that didn't work either.